# High response time with pingdom

Tags: monitoring, performance-monitoring, performance-tuning, performance-counters

I have a server hosted at my end, I am monitoring the server with pingdom and also my router. Strange thing is the response time towards the router is fine, but when the traffic flows towards the server, the response time became relatively high. It's more than 1000ms. Can anyone help me with it?

Comment: How fast and how contended is the connection "at your end"?  Where are you based in comparison to the Pingdom test nodes? You can't break the speed of light.

Comment: Hi, the response time from Pingdom to my router is 264ms, and if I ping from my router to my server, it takes less than 1ms. But when Pingdom monitor my server, it takes around 1100-1200ms. Any clue on it? Thanks

Comment: 240ms a few times back and fortg for multiple (http) objects adds up to your 1000-1100ms quickly.

Comment: Hi, but when I check it from Just Ping, the response time from the server is only 200-400ms average. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't specify what type of check you have Pingdom performing.  However, my guess is you are doing an HTTP check.  In this case Pingdom issues a full HTTP request for your site and the response time is the total time of the request to be sent, received, acknowledged, and for data to fully transfer.  So the 1100-1200ms you see is the combination of the request as well as the total amount of time it took for your site to "load" on the Pingdom virtual browser/server.

Given that and the lack of information you provide this all sounds about right, 1.1 to 1.2 seconds to fully load.

Comment: This is correct. Pingdom's name can be somewhat misleading, suggesting that they are doing UDP pings to an address (which should probably have ICMP disabled anyway). In fact, they are doing a single HTTP GET request of a given page, minus any associated assets.

Comment: Hi Brent and platforms, thanks a lot for your answers. I can get a clearer picture now. Very much appreciate.